# What are the safest and more convenient settings for tally2?

Tags: login

So tally2 allows you to lock the login system after entering the wrong password a certain amount of times.

So in

```
/etc/pam.d/common-auth
```

the entry:

```
auth    required           pam_tally2.so onerr=fail deny=5 unlock_time=1200 audit
```

defines the number of unsuccessful login attempts that will lock the account
and the time to unlock so we can keep trying (`unlock_time`, in seconds)

So, the question is what are there clear rules on what combination of settings 'deny'/'unlock_time' have to be used depending on the level of security need it.

By default is 5/1200 but waiting 10 min can be a pain if you do not remember the password and want to try a few. If a hacker does not know the password and has to guess he/she will need to try thousands of passwords. So, 5 looks like a very small number. May be 100/1200 would be better? So, if you are not sure of your password can guess more times without locking the system. For a brute force attack, 5 or 100 will not make a difference. Or to be safer you could increase time 100/3600. This allows you to try many possible passwords but for a hacker makes it too long.

On the other hand, locking every fail or two for a short period of time, would also work. For example 2/60. So 2 attempts every minute. This will also disrupt an attack but will not be a pain if you have to try a few possible passwords.

Is there any serious study on how these settings can impact security?

Comment: The safest way is automatically the least convenient one.

Comment: So, what is the tradeoff? I am sure these numbers are not left randomly. I imagine someone has thought about the best combination

Comment: I'm afraid "best" depends on the concrete attack scenario you are considering, so without any further information the answers here can only be speculative. You may want to try it over at [Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: security stackExchange?? wow there are stacks for everything... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion locking for long time makes none sense. It can only make legitimate user ‘ life miserable. You should think that a legitimate user can forget a password but probably will try 5-6 passwords, may be more than once each one.

An attack would need to try thousands of potential password.

Now, if you lock every 1-5 password attempts the user might enter the right password during lock time, and making the user believe that password is wrong.

Better allow for 10-20 attempts and then block for a minute. That would be enough to abort brute force attacks but allow many attempts for a forgetful user

This is safe and convenient

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Nice point on leaving enough tries to the legitimate user! So 20/30s should be good.